# Python With Google Sheets Can't Write to Col B

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets, google-api, gspread

I've got two lists, and I'm trying to write them to columns A and B of a google sheets doc, respectively, but I can only get it to write to column A, just alternating in rows.

Here's what I've tried that writes to !A,

```
sheet.insert_row(fList)
sheet.insert_row(gList)
```

And here's what I've tried to adding it to COL !A-!B

```
    rows = [fList, gList]
    for row in rows:
        for column in row:
            sheet.insert_row(column)
        sheet.add_cols(1)
```

Which resulted in an error saying it was an invalid data type. How do I get it to do what I'm asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- `fList` and `gList` are 1 dimensional array.
- You want to put the values of `fList` and `gList` to the columns "A" and "B", respectively.
- You want to achieve this using gspread for Python.

In your situation, how about using the method of "update"? The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
fList = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'] # Please set your actual value.
gList = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5'] # Please set your actual value.
spreadsheetId = "###" # Please set your Spreadsheet ID.
sheetName = "Sheet1" # Please set your sheet name.

rows = [fList, gList]
client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
spreadsheet = client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId)
sheet = spreadsheet.worksheet(sheetName)
length = max(map(len, rows)) # If the array length of "fList" and "gList" are the same, this line is not required to be used.
rows = [e + [''] * (length - len(e)) for e in rows] # If the array length of "fList" and "gList" are the same, this line is not required to be used.
sheet.update('A1', [list(e) for e in zip(*rows)])
```

#### Reference:

- [update(range_name, values=None, **kwargs)](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=update#gspread.models.Worksheet.update)

### Added:

For my following comment,

> @GabeCunningham Unfortunately, I cannot understand about It is two lists, not a lot of lists. The values of `fList` and `gList` are `fList = [['781411'],['781415'],['781412'],['781416'],['701355'],['70‌​1330'],['701346'],['‌​701352'],['782153'],‌​['701354'],['781347'‌​],['781345']]` and `gList = [['$81.57'],['$80.91'],['$91.63'],['$91.63'],['$455.20'],['$‌​196.90'],['$282.60']‌​,['$146.10'],['$97.2‌​2'],['$166.70'],['$2‌​87.30'],['$237.50']]‌​`?

You said as follows.

> Correct, yes. Those are those lists

From this situation, I added one more sample script using the values of `fList = [['781411'],['781415'],['781412'],['781416'],['701355'],['70‌​1330'],['701346'],['‌​701352'],['782153'],‌​['701354'],['781347'‌​],['781345']]` and `gList = [['$81.57'],['$80.91'],['$91.63'],['$91.63'],['$455.20'],['$‌​196.90'],['$282.60']‌​,['$146.10'],['$97.2‌​2'],['$166.70'],['$2‌​87.30'],['$237.50']]‌​`.

#### Sample script:

```
spreadsheetId = "###" # Please set your Spreadsheet ID.
sheetName = "Sheet1" # Please set your sheet name.

# These values are from your comment.
fList = [['781411'], ['781415'], ['781412'], ['781416'], ['701355'], ['701330'], ['701346'], ['701352'], ['782153'], ['701354'], ['781347'], ['781345']]
gList = [['$81.57'], ['$80.91'], ['$91.63'], ['$91.63'], ['$455.20'], ['$196.90'], ['$282.60'], ['$146.10'], ['$97.22'], ['$166.70'], ['$287.30'], ['$237.50']]

rows = [sum(fList, []), sum(gList, [])]
client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
spreadsheet = client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId)
sheet = spreadsheet.worksheet(sheetName)
sheet.update('A1', [list(e) for e in zip(*rows)])
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229427/discussion-on-answer-by-tanaike-python-with-google-sheets-cant-write-to-col-b).